# WHM/Cpanel 11.38.2 (build 6) with Easy::Apache v3.22.7 broken when upgrading from Apache 2.2.x to 2.4.x

Tags: apache, cpanel, whm

Today, I tried rebuilding my Apache, moving from 2.2.x to 2.4.x.

It built okay, but when it got to the end, when doing something with the httpd.conf files, I got an error...

```
!! Failed to generate a syntactically correct Apache configuration (/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf.1377752843):
Configuration problem detected on line 68 of file /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf.1377752843: Either all Options must start with + or -, or no Option may.

    --- /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf.1377752843 ---
    62ScriptAlias /mailman /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/mailman/cgi-bin/
    63ScriptAlias /scgi-bin /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/scgiwrap
    64
    65
    66<Directory "/">
    67    AllowOverride All
    68 ===>     Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks Includes IncludesNOEXEC -Indexes -MultiViews SymLinksIfOwnerMatch <===
    69</Directory>
    70
    71<Directory "/usr/local/apache/htdocs">
    72    Options All
    73    AllowOverride None
    74    Require all granted
    --- /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf.1377752843 ---
```

I am at a loss at what to do. WHM creates this file from the UI, based on options selected in the Apache Global config Editor. I believe modifying this file by hand wouldn't be prudent as its auto generated whenever you modify your setup, etc.

I think this is a bug in WHM at the moment as it's not handling the config file rule changes when moving from 2.2.x to 2.4.x.

Anyone have any suggestions at what to do?

At the moment, Easy Apache rolls back (thankfully). So I'm stuck at 2.2.x.

Thanks,
Rich

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not totally certain, but I tried updating all of my WHM software, and something got updated (Easy Apache also was updated version 3.22.10 today 8/29/2013). I tried building apache 2.4.x today and it worked.

This question can be closed.

Rich